# Bitcoin gone missing

Tags: electrum, coinbase.com

I've sent bitcoins from one wallet to another, the transaction has over 30 confirmations but its not even appearing in my wallet as pending. Ive checked the address and it matches. What could be the issue? It was from coinbase to electrum.

Comment: Have you checked the receiving public address at Blockchain.info to see if the transfer shows up on the blockchain? If I understand correctly, Electrum wallets are light, so they reference the blockchain without having to sync with it. So, if the transfer shows up it might be a glitch in the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

May be:

1. You sent to incorrect address
2. Electrum have not synchronized yet